# An informative contour plot

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to visualise the graph of a function $f(x,y)$ of two real variables using `ContourPlot`. Here are the things I'm after:

- The points where $f(x,y)=0$ should be easily seen. This can be done with a separate `ContourPlot` of the form `ContourPlot[f[x,y]==0,{x,x1,x2},{y,y1,y2}]`.
- There should be a clear distinction between the areas where $f(x,y)>0$ and $f(x,y)<0$. For example, the positive areas will coloured in shades of green, and the negative ones with shades of red.
- The plot should be symmetric with respect to the contour line $f(x,y)=0$. That is, if we're using different shades of green and red say, the points where $f(x,y)=10$ should have the same brightness as those where $f(x,y)=-10$.

---

To give an example, I'm not satisfied with the default

```
ContourPlot[y-x^2,{x,-5,5},{y,-5,5}]
```

since it's not easy to tell the positive and negative areas apart.

I would appreciate any help on this. Thanks!

Comment: You can use `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`, which means that the values of the function will be directly passed to the colour function, without rescaling.  Then you can identify where 0 is, precisely.  But you need to write your own colour function.  For example, `Show[
 DensityPlot[y - x^2 == 0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -3, 7}, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["ThermometerColors"][
      1/2 + ArcTan[.2 #]/Pi] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  PlotPoints -> 50],
 ContourPlot[y - x^2 == 0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -3, 7}, 
  ContourStyle -> Directive[Black, Dashed]]
 ]`

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks! I'd like the transition from positive to negative to be sharper though, and also instead of the blue-red colors your picture has, use red-green respectively. Can this be done?

Comment: You could use `Rescale[]` (@Szabolcs ;) ) along with maybe the `"RedGreenSplit"` gradient.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I'm afraid I'm not fluent enough in Mathematica to use your comment.

Comment: To add to @Szabolcs's suggestion, you can skip the generation of the separate `ContourPlot[]` by adding `Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, MeshStyle -> Directive[Black, Dashed]`. user, Szabolcs here asked a question about `Rescale[]`; try looking for it under his profile.

Comment: @user1337 You simply need to define the mapping from numbers to colours yourself.  Please check my example on how to do that and if there are any bits that are unclear, ask about them specifically.  You can use predefined gradients (look up `ColorData`) or make your own with `Blend`. These gradients will transforms numbers in $[0,1]$ to colours.  You additionally need to transform your functions values into the $[0,1]$ to be able to feed it to the colour function.  I choose an `ArcTan` based solution for that, but you can choose something else.

Answer (score 4):

As I understand your requirements, the following should meet them.

```
ContourPlot[x y^2 + x^3, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
  Contours -> 15, 
  ColorFunction -> (If[# > .5, RGBColor[#, 0, 0], RGBColor[0, 1 - #, 0]] &)]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you! This seems to achieve what I'm after for this particular function. But if you use `y-x^2` instead the change from green to red doesn't happen at the right contour.

Answer (score 4):

I'll use a [`Blend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blend.html) that is specified at three values, but you could use more.

```
With[{
  blend := 
   Blend[{{MinValue[{y - x^2, -5 < x < 5 && -5 < y < 5}, {x, y}], 
       Red}, {0, 
       Black}, {MaxValue[{y - x^2, -5 < x < 5 && -5 < y < 5}, {x, y}],
        Green}}, #] &},
 ContourPlot[y - x^2, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, ColorFunction -> blend, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
 ]
```

> [image: Out]

Adding two more `Blend` value specifications to reduce the extend of the black area:

```
With[{
  blend := 
   Blend[{{MinValue[{x y^2 + x^3, -5 < x < 5 && -5 < y < 5}, {x, y}], 
       Red}, {-1, Darker[Red, 0.85]}, {0, 
       Black}, {MaxValue[{x y^2 + x^3, -5 < x < 5 && -5 < y < 5}, {x, 
         y}], Green}, {1, Darker[Green, 0.85]}}, #] &},
 ContourPlot[x y^2 + x^3, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, Contours -> 30, 
  ColorFunction -> blend, ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
 ]
```

> [image: Out2]

As a function with symmetric coloring:

```
myCP[f_, {x_, xmin_, xmax_}, {y_, ymin_, ymax_}, opts : OptionsPattern[ListLogPlot]] := 
 Module[{minmax = 
    Max[-MinValue[{f, xmin < x < xmax && ymin < y < ymax}, {x, y}], 
     MaxValue[{f, xmin < x < xmax && ymin < y < ymax}, {x, y}]],
   blend},
  blend = Blend[{{-minmax, Red}, {-minmax/100, Darker[Red, 0.9]}, {0, Black}, 
   {minmax/100, Darker[Green, 0.9]}, {minmax, Green}}, #] &;
  ContourPlot[f, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, opts, 
   ColorFunction -> blend, ColorFunctionScaling -> False]]

myCP[y - x^2, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, Contours -> 20]
```

> [image: Out3]

Comment: Thanks Karsten. However, I'd like the colors to be darker at lower values, and not the other way around.

Comment: @user1337 like this one?

Comment: I'm not completely satisfied with the first plot, but the second looks great. I'm going to test it for different functions `f` soon.